# saving seekbar value to the database

Tags: java, android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I am stuck a bit with a problem. I want to get the value of seekbar to be posted to the database. How can i get that value to be used in here:

This code is again at the bottom:

```
 public void poslji (View view){

        String poslji_data = test.getText().toString().trim();
        String type ="Poslji";
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
        backgroundWorker.execute(type, poslji_data);
        }
}
```

This is the whole code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

   // private TextView test;
    private TextView textView;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private SeekBar seekBar;
    private TextView strI;

    EditText test;


    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
       setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

       seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById( seek_bar_id );

        test = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.test_id);

       initializeVariables();

       textView.setText( "Jakost bolečine: " + seekBar.getProgress() + "/" + seekBar.getMax() );

       seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
           int progress = 0;

           @Override
           public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
               progress = progresValue;
           }

           @Override
           public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
           }

           @Override
           public void onStopTrackingTouch(final SeekBar seekBar) {

               textView.setText( "Jakost bolečine: " + progress + "/" + seekBar.getMax() );
               if (progress == 0) {

                   imageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.no_pain );
               }
               if (progress <= 2 && progress >= 1) {
                   imageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.little_pain );
                   Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Blaga bolečina!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
               }

               if (progress <= 4 && progress >= 3) {
                   imageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.moderata_pain );
                   Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Zmerna bolečina!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
               }

               if (progress <= 6 && progress >= 5) {
                   imageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.severe_pain );
                   Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Srednja bolečina!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
               }

               if (progress <= 8 && progress >= 7) {
                   imageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.very_severe_pain );
                   Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Dokaj močna bolečina!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
               }

               if (progress <= 10 && progress >= 9) {
                   imageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.worst_pain );
                   Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Zelo močna bolečina!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
               }


               String strI = String.valueOf(progress);


           }

       } );


   }
    private void initializeVariables() {
        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar_id);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jakost_bolecin_id);
        //test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
        imageView=(ImageView)findViewById( R.id.slika_bolecine );

    }

    public void poslji (View view){

        String poslji_data = test.getText().toString().trim();
        String type ="Poslji";
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
        backgroundWorker.execute(type, poslji_data);
        }
}
```

Comment: all i get in database is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SeekBar` is a subclass of `ProgressBar` which has a [getProgress()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#getProgress%28%29) method. So, you can use it to get the current progress inside your `poslji` method. No need to keep track of the progress when its changing.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) :

> A SeekBar is an extension of ProgressBar that adds a draggable thumb.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an excellent use case for an [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)